# linear ODE problem

Tags: differential-equations, oc.optimization-and-control

I'm having a trouble with this optimal control problem:
$$\min_u J(x,u) = \min_u\{\int_0^\infty -u(\frac{ct}{ct+cf}Q+\alpha x+\beta u) dt$$
$$\dot x=(\alpha x+\beta u)(\frac{1}{ct}+\frac{1}{cf})$$
where:$\,\,\,\,ct, cf ,Q\gt0,\,\,\,\alpha,\beta\lt0$ and constant

after I constructed the state, costate and the stationery equations i got:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        \dot x\\
        \dot p\\
        \end{pmatrix}
         =\begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{\alpha}{2}(\frac{1}{ct}+\frac{1}{cf})) & \beta(\frac{1}{ct}+\frac{1}{cf})^2 \\
        -\frac{\alpha^2}{4\beta} & -\frac{\alpha}{2}(\frac{1}{ct}+\frac{1}{cf})) \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        x\\
        p\\
        \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
        -\frac{Q}{2cf}\\
        -\frac{\alpha Qct}{4*b*(cf + ct)}\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$p$ is the lagrange multiplier.
I stucked here. this matrix is singular.
How can i solve a singular (2x2) hamiltanion matrix?
can i solve it using the exponential matrix?
I got really tired of searching. l'll be grateful if any body give me a push? Thanks

Comment: You may want to check the calculations carefully. I get a different Hamiltonian system than yours.

Comment: i re-checked it, i even used MATLAB to make sure. i think it is correctly done

Comment: In your equation of the form $\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}\\ \dot{p}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}M_{11} & M_{12}\\ M_{21} & M_{22}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ p\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} m_{1}\\ m_{2} \end{pmatrix}$, my $M_{12}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ times yours, my $M_{21}$ is 2 times yours, my $m_{2}$ is 2 times yours. Also, you need to be careful about typing. The formula you typed has several issues: multiple unbalanced parentheses, $b$ instead of $\beta$ etc.